# CTRL+click not working on Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, tabbed-browsing

As in the title, that shortcut doesn't work, and I can open a new tab only with pushing the scroll. Since the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key works perfectly in the other environments, what's wrong with Chrome?

I'm using the latest Chrome on Windows 7 Home Premium on a Samsung NP305V5A-S03IT.

**Update:** I changed laptop two months ago, and it's not working since then. In the previous one it was working, so I know that it *should* work.

I could also try to reinstall, but since it's annoying I would like to try simpler solutions first.

Comment: Since when does it fail to do that? Have you installed anything?

Comment: Does not work on *any* site or just on certain sites? Find that some sites are coded weirdly and `Ctrl+Click` and/or `Middle-Click` do not work. `Right-Click->Open New` always does though (at least on real links; you cannot open JavaScript "link" in a new tab/window).

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this in Chrome with all extensions disabled. It happens in Chrome on only 1 computer (Latitude E6540, Win 7 Pro). Other browsers on that computer work fine and Chrome on other computers work fine. It happens on [msn.com](http://msn.com) and [drudgereport.com](http://drudgereport.com). Very frustrating!

Comment: I found that the [middle button new tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/middle-button-new-tab/ikbkhpkapkmhaoiabhlkmicpeakhhpip) extension fixes the problem even though I'm not using the middle button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have the same Samsung modelled specified by the OP. It came with an extension installed called [Word CaptureX](http://www.wordcapture.com/overview). When I disabled this extension, <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> worked again perfectly. Strangely, it only didn't work with google sites.

Comment: I disabled the extension, and at a first look it seems to work properly. Many thanks!

Comment: I hate "features" like this -- it's one of the reasons that I use Linux.

Answer (score 3):

It works for my Chrome. And it should be the norm, if I believe this [list of keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179).

So you most likely have an issue only inside your installation of Chrome. There is no way to edit these shortcuts, as far as I'm aware. Try to reinstall Chrome, [check the extensions](http://chrome://settings/extensions) which are installed, as they could alter the default behaviour. Try for example to deactivate all of them, and see if you have the issue or not.

Check if it works with another browser, to see if it's related only to Chrome, or if another program is somehow blocking that.

Comment: As in the edit: it used to work in the other PC, now it doesn't.

Comment: I Second that. Maybe one of your extensions is using control as a hotkey?

Comment: Hey, just to tell you that the issue was related to an extension, as Bob found :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it is an extension; it's probably Chrome behaving badly. I used to have this problem too, but only on a select few websites. I'm not sure if the problem was solved (I no longer have it on Youtube) or I simply adapted my behavior by learning to right-click and select "open in new tab" without thinking when needed. Here's [the old complaint thread on the Google Chrome forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/DmVAViloos4) I participated in.

You might want to check if your middle mouse still does the right thing (if you have a mouse like that to plug in); for me, both CTRL+Click and MiddleClick broke in the same way.

@Gnoupi: Installed extensions on the current Chrome dev are at [chrome://chrome/extensions/](http://chrome://chrome/extensions/), not the link you gave...

Comment: I think mine also works in some pages, but the middle works everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

Drudgereport.com blocks opening links in new tabs via JavaScript. Firefox specifically disallows this type of bad behavior; Chrome allows it. I have to disable all JS on DrudgeReport.com (which loses me nothing but annoying ads :) and CTRL+Click works again.